# How to test RESTful web services using "Test restful web service" option in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: rest, intellij-idea

In our project we are using IntelliJ IDEA. There is an option to test RESTful web services (Tools -> Web Services -> RESTful Web Service -> Test RESTful Web Service).  How would I pass in request XML if I choose request header data content-type as `application/xml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose files to be sent but there's no input area for free text to be sent as the request body.

Maybe that usefull feature will be included in a next version. More info [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/rest-client-tool-window.html).

Answer (score 2):

You should use the **Request** tab and in Headers panel add new parameter as :

```
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

then in request body choose the text radio button then insert your json content in the text box. 
[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer. Please note that you need to use HTTP Method POST, PUT or Patch otherwise sending content in the body of the request is not available.